# When I download files using the Google Drive API, the file name is instead the file id. How can I change this?

Tags: php, api, google-drive-api

I'm new to the Google Drive API and I've been using it in a sort of an unorthodox manner. Right now I have just an API key to authenticate and I download files using the `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/file-id?alt=media&key=api-key` scheme. This can successfully download files, except that their name is actually just the file ID without any extension. I've tried a few things so far including setting headers in my PHP code that define `content-type`, `content-disposition`, and even `content-length` attributes, but that used my server's bandwidth even if used properly. I've also tried that HTML `download` attribute for `a` tags, but I found it only works with blobs or local files. I've also tried some Javascript to no avail. Here is part of my code right now, which uses blobs to download and rename the file, however I would like to not have to go this route and seek a better option:

```
<?php

$id = "SOME-ID-HERE";
$key = "API-KEY-HERE"; // Google Drive API Key
$pre = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/";

$dlink = $pre.$id."?alt=media&key=".$key;

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
a = document.createElement('a'), file;

xhr.open('GET', '<?php echo $dlink ?>', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function () {
    file = new Blob([xhr.response], { type : 'application/octet-stream' });
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    a.download = 'filename.ext';

    a.click();
};
xhr.send();
</script>
```

As you can see, I'm not even using the Drive API PHP libraries, I'm just using their link which either returns the file contents or the metadata of the file. I suspect that this is why the file being downloaded is renamed to just the file ID, but I don't know for sure. Since I don't want to use blobs unless I have to, my main question is: Can I use the Drive API (properly by including the PHP libraries for it) to download files from Google Drive, but have them be named exactly as how they are already named in Google Drive? Secondly, if this is possible, does it use my server's bandwidth for serving the files or is it directly from Google's servers? I want to try to avoid using my server's bandwidth if possible to accomplish this.

**UPDATE:** I have a server here that works for this but it's a hacky method of getting it to work. I would still feel safer using the API because it's future proof. 
https://drivedl.cf/file-id

I wouldn't recommend using it yet though, it works but there's some potential bugs I need to weed out

**UPDATE 2:** `https://drivedl.cf/file-id` is currently unusable because I'm working on it right now, trying to use the API but It's giving me issues

Comment: If you only want to show direct links to the files and it's OK for anyone to be able to download them try generating links like this: " https://drive.google.com/uc?id=SOME-ID-HERE&authuser=0&export=download ". This will take users to google drive, to the file in question and force the browser to download, but it only works if you share the files so 'everyone with a link can view'. If you want something else, maybe someone here will have an answer or you will find it in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk)

Comment: I knew about this method long before and it doesn't work for files over 25 mb because it will show a virus scan warning. I want a real direct download link that works for anything no matter what. But thanks for trying to help anyways.